# HAProxy connections to second and third node, should be only to the first node

Tags: load-balancing, mariadb, haproxy, galera

This is our `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`

```
global
  daemon
  stats  socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
  maxconn  10000
  mode  tcp
  timeout  connect 5s
  timeout  client 30s
  timeout  server 30s

listen galera
  bind 192.168.55.19:3306
  option httpchk
  option tcplog
  stick on dst
  stick-table type ip size 2
  timeout client 90m
  timeout server 90m
  server galera-1 192.168.55.31:3306 check inter 1s port 9200 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
  server galera-2 192.168.55.32:3306 check inter 1s port 9200 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions
  server galera-3 192.168.55.33:3306 check inter 1s port 9200 on-marked-down shutdown-sessions

listen monitor
  bind 127.0.0.01:9300
  mode http
  monitor-uri /status
  stats enable
  stats uri /admin
  stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
  stats auth root:Eef7ye9Aeemu7Cei
  stats refresh 5s
```

We wish to do connections only to the first node galera-1. galera-2 and galera-3 should be only failover.

I see with netstat quite a lot of connections. Why? Howto troubleshoot?

```
# netstat -tupan | grep 192.168.55.32
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59482        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59466        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:54498        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:45546        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:54430        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59502        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59515        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:60039        192.168.55.32:3306         TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59454        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59523        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59518        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
tcp        0      0 192.168.55.34:59413        192.168.55.32:3306         ESTABLISHED 5045/haproxy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fail Overs**

If you want `galera-2` and `galera-3` to only be fail-overs, add the `backup` keyword to its `server` line.

**Multiple Connections**

Looks normal to me. These might be opened by your MySQL client or app connecting to the DB. To confirm what these connections are for, you may use a packet sniffer like Wireshark (run from client) or `tcpdump` (from server).

---

**Some comments on your setup**:

- 1 active and 2 backups seems to be overkill. Are you expecting a lot of failures for these servers?
- Stick tables doesn't make sense when you only have 1 active server.
- Is that your actual root password you use in the Monitor block?!

Comment: no I faked the root password. Please write more about the `keepalived TCP connections` on MySQL port. I didn't understand why.

Comment: I corrected my answer. I just realized you're LB/proxying MySQL instead of a web server.